# total search result from youtube api without error

Tags: python, api, youtube

I'm trying to get a search list for a specific keyword from the YouTube API. Total result is 1000000 but i got 307 data for videos after that thiss error is showing.

<HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=Hindi+Dubbed+Full+Movie&part=snippet&type=video&maxResults=50&key=KEY&alt=json returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).". Details: "[{'message': 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).', 'domain': 'youtube.quota', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded'}]">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  With all due respects, I think the error is very self explanatory.   You have exceeded your quota.    Please check if you have enough quota to make this type of request.  Refer to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded your maximum request limit via the YouTube API. You get videos from a YouTube page and the total number of results before the quota exceeded was 307 videos.

Comment: how i get 1 million result from youtube

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Akeel Medina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20095815/akeel-medina) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73861573/7123660):

> YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint is limited to 500 results:
>
> > **Note**: Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the **channelId** parameter and sets the [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter value to **video**, but it does not also set one of the [forContentOwner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forContentOwner), [forDeveloper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forDeveloper), or [forMine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) filters.
>
> Source: [Search: list#channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId)
>
> Note that this 500 limit seems to happen not only for the documentation described case.

As described below this limit can't be bypassed by reverse-engineering YouTube UI Search feature:

> YouTube UI search by query term (`Test` here) when filtering for only retrieving videos stopped after `549` results (filtered `ago` as a whole word and filtering with `view` gives a similar result)...
>
> When not filtering for only retrieving videos stopped after `654` results (filtered `ago` as a whole word).
> Filtering with:
>
> - `view` gives 702 matches
> - `VIEW FULL PLAYLIST` gives 2 matches, so can guess there are this number of playlists
> - `subscriber` gives 44 matches, so can guess there are this number of channels

Source: https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4